# C++ program won't write to .dat file

Tags: c++, file

I've been stumped with this problem I'm having with my C++ program, where the program opens a file, prompts the user to select a record from the file, reads out the record, and then prompts the user to enter in info for the record to be saved to the file. The issue is that for whatever reason, running the program again will show that none of the information from the previous entry has been saved. Here's the code:

```
//This program allows the user to edit a specific
//record in the inventory file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int DESC_SIZE = 31;
//Declaration of Invtry structure
struct Invtry{
    char desc[DESC_SIZE];
    int qty;
    double wholesaleCost;
    double retailCost;
    int dateDay;
    int dateMonth;
    int dateYear;
};

int main(){
    //Variables needed to read the file
    Invtry record;
    long recNum;

    //Open the file
    fstream inventory("invtry.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!inventory){
        cout << "Error opening file";
        return 0;
    }

    //Move to the desired record and read it into record
    cout << "Which record do you want to edit?";
    cin >> recNum;
    inventory.seekg(recNum * sizeof(record), ios::beg);
    inventory.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&record), sizeof(record));

    //Get new data from user and edit in-memory record
    cout << "Description: ";
    cout << record.desc << endl;
    cout << "Quantity: ";
    cout << record.qty << endl;
    cout << "Wholesale Cost: ";
    cout << record.wholesaleCost << endl;
    cout << "Retail Cost: ";
    cout << record.retailCost << endl;
    cout << "Date Added: ";
    cout << record.dateMonth << "/" << record.dateDay << "/" << record.dateYear << endl;
    cout << "Enter the new data:\n";
    cout << "Description: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(record.desc, DESC_SIZE);
    cout << "Quantity: ";
    cin >> record.qty;
    cout << "Wholesale Cost: ";
    cin >> record.wholesaleCost;
    cout << "Retail Cost: ";
    cin >> record.retailCost;
    cout << "Date: Month: ";
    cin >> record.dateMonth;
    cout << "Date: Day: ";
    cin >> record.dateDay;
    cout << "Date: Year: ";
    cin >> record.dateYear;



    //Move to the right place in file and write the record
    inventory.seekp(recNum * sizeof(record), ios::beg);
    inventory.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&record),sizeof(record));

    //Close the file
    inventory.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I've checked if it's an issue of how the .dat file is being created, but it doesn't seem to be the issue. Regardless, here's the code for how the .dat file is made:

```
//This program sets up a file of blank inventory records
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int DESC_SIZE = 31, NUM_RECORDS = 5;
//Declaration of Invtry structure
struct Invtry{
    char desc[DESC_SIZE];
    int qty;
    double wholesaleCost;
    double retailCost;
    int dateDay;
    int dateMonth;
    int dateYear;
};

int main(){
    //Variables needed to write the file
    Invtry record = {"",0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0};

    //Create file object and open file
    fstream inventory("invtry.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!inventory){
        cout << "Error opening file.";
        return 0;
    }

    //Now write the blank records
    for (int count = 0; count < NUM_RECORDS; count ++){
        cout << "Now writing record " << count << endl;
        inventory.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&record),sizeof(record));
    }
    //close the file
    inventory.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What input do you give your program? More specifically, what is the input for `recNum`?

Comment: I generally test recNum with an input of 1. I wrote cin.ignore() because of cin.getline() just after it, so that the description isn't the input for the quantity.

Comment: You are aware that a `recNum` of 1 will not give you the 1st record in the file, but rather the second one. Are you looking at the right record?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that the file starts at 0. I believe this problem would affect any number within the range of records.

Comment: The next step I would take, if I found myself in a similar situation, is to run the program under `strace` so that I can observe the exact syscalls that come out, and see exactly what it does or does not read and write. In other situations I would use my debugger, first; but the shown code is fairly straightforward, and I don't see much that a debugger could possibly tell me. `strace` is the next step.

Comment: No I don't think so, @drescherjm. If `recNum` is 1, and `sizeof(record)` is (spitballing here) 40, seeking to position -39 in the file is not going to accomplish anything useful. Besides, the OP confirmed that `recNum` is meant to be 0-based.

Comment: I meant `inventory.seekg((recNum-1)* sizeof(record), ios::beg);` as I doubt the user will type 0 based unless instructed.

Comment: replacing recNum with recNum - 1 doesn't fix the issue. The issue isn't that I'm reading and writing into the incorrect spots on the .dat file, but that it just wont write anything at all. It's like the write() function doesn't do anything

Comment: Are you sure your looking at the correct file?

Comment: I'm fairly certain I'm looking at the right file.

Comment: I just tested this on Rocky linux and your write code does write a file that is 360 bytes in length: [https://justpaste.it/623eo](https://justpaste.it/623eo)

Comment: @DanielLippold Re: `I'm fairly certain I'm looking at the right file` - I am pretty sure you are not. Your code creates and updates the file OK.

Comment: @VladFeinstein I feel like such an idiot right now. I double checked, and apparently the file that was being used was the blank one the second program generates, not the actual file within the folder of my program. Entering in the exact path fixed my issue. Thank you!

Comment: That was going to be my guess. That the writing program wrote the file in a different location. The first program (that opens for read and write) will create a blank file if one does not exist because of the `ios::out` part of the flags.